# How do I style this link without the entire block being selected?

Tags: html, css

I want to style Forget Password element so that it appears in the right side. This is possible with width set to 100% but I'm also observing that the empty space before the text is also carrying the link property. I tried using width as 50%, but this pushes the text back to the left side. How can I achieve what I want?

```css
#forgotP {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <form autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <p><a href="#" target="_black" id="forgotP">Forgot Password?</a></p>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Register" id="register" class="inline">
    <input type="button" value="Login" id="login" class="inline">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS flexbox to get it done.

```css
.box {
  width: max-content;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#forgotP {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="box">
    <form autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>

      <p><a href="#" target="_black" id="forgotP">Forgot Password?</a></p>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
      <input type="button" value="Register" id="register" class="inline">
      <input type="button" value="Login" id="login" class="inline">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

add CSS code

```
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working. The empty space before Forget Password is still linked.

Comment: @Nikhat The other way to around is the use css flex. l added css to my previous answer and use css flexbox. Try it let me know if it works.

Comment: This works, thank you!